# JQuery timer : is it advisable to use it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

JQuery timer : is it advisable to use it? or is it better to use Javascript native timer?

[Jquery timer example](http://jquery.offput.ca/every/)

Comment: I'm interested in what you mean by "advisable" and "better" - can you be any clearer?

Comment: in term of performance which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That plugin uses setInterval - I take it that's what you're referring to when you say "Javascript native timer" - and adds a bit of extra functionality on top. If you're already using jQuery, and you find yourself doing a lot of time-based stuff, I'd say it's highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

If the rest of your code is jQuery rather than vanilla JS, use the jQuery timer.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery timers can be used in the same line as jQuery selectors, etc. and can be passed the function to execute as a block instead of a string.  I would use it unless I had absolutely no other use for jQuery in my application, in which case I couldn't justify having my users load the library.